# Help with this problem

Tags: calculus

I'm stuck on this problem and I'm not sure what I'm missing. The problem states:

Assume that $|f''(x)| \leq m$ for each $x$ in the interval $[0,a]$, and assume that $f$ takes on its largest value at an interior point of this interval. Show that $|f'(0)| + |f'(a)| \leq am$. You may assume that $f''$ is continuous on $[0,a]$.

I first observed that using the Mean Value Theorem for integrals and letting $c$ be a number in the interval $[0,a]$, I can obtain
$$
\int_0^a|f''(t)|\,dt = |f''(c)|.(a-0) \leq m.a
$$
I also observed that, using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, I can also obtain
$$
\int_0^a|f''(t)|\,dt = |f'(a)| - |f'(0)|
$$
which would imply
$$
|f'(a)| - |f'(0)| \leq m.a
$$
I know that
$$
0\leq|f'(a)| - |f'(0)| \leq |f'(a) - f'(0)| \leq |f'(a)| + |f'(0)|
$$
but I haven't been able to determine what the next step is. Based on the above information, I can't see how I can deduce the answer from what I have so far, so I'm clearly missing something. Any Hints would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I (finally) came up with:
I (incorrectly) deduced from the FTC that
$$
\int_0^a|f''(t)|\,dt = |f'(a)|-[f'(0)|
$$
The correct deduction to make is as follows:
Given that $f$ takes on its largest value at an interior point of $[0,a]$, it follows that there exists a number $d$ in $[0,a]$ such that $f'(d) = 0$. 
Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we can deduce
$$
\int_0^df''(t)\,dt = f'(d) - f'(0) = -f'(0)
$$
and
$$
\int_d^af''(t)\,dt = f'(a) - f'(d) = f'(a)
$$
Therefore
$$
|\int_0^df''(t)\,dt| = |-f'(0)| = |f'(0)|
$$
and
$$
|\int_d^af''(t)\,dt| = |f'(a)|
$$
But
$$
|\int_0^df''(t)\,dt| \leq \int_0^d|f''(t)|\,dt
$$
So
$$
\int_0^d|f''(t)|\,dt \geq |f'(0)|
$$
Similarly
$$
\int_d^a|f''(t)|\,dt \geq |f'(a)|
$$
Which means
$$
\int_0^a|f''(t)|\,dt \geq |f'(0)| + |f'(a)|
$$
and we thus have the following inequality
$$
ma \geq \int_0^a|f''(t)|\,dt \geq |f'(0)| + |f'(a)|
$$
Consequently
$$
|f'(0)| + |f'(a)| \leq ma
$$